# JS use uploaded image before upload

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use image that the user select in an upload field before it's really uploaded server side. Specifically I want to let the user manipulate the image (crop, lightning etc) with some jquery plugin before he actually upload it.

I'm don't have so much experience with JS, so so far I ended up with this code:

```
$(".image_upload_form").submit(function (e) {
    "use strict";
    e.preventDefault();
    var input, files, reader;
    input = $("#id_image");
    files = input[0].files;
    if (files && files[0]) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img_view').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
});
```

which works fine, the image is shown on the `"#img_view"` after the form is submitted. But I need to get the `"e.target.result"` in the `reader.onload` function into a variable, so I can use it in later code. how can I do that?

Comment: well you have to have a temp storage to do so , first the user selects the image ,then you store it into some temp storage on your server , after the user is done operating the image , then you need to store it on the server DB when the user submits the form .

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid I know, it's just that I'm very limited in resources so I want the process to be on the client side.

Comment: yeah i already gave u the alternative ,but thats also limited , cant use on IE until u use IE10 or above , rest its fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well if you are considering IE , the this will work on all browsers , almost on every main browser

```
function selectedPhotoText(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imagePreview')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(240)
                        .height(149);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else {
        $('#imagePreview').attr('src', "../../Images/blqblq.jpg");
    }
}

<img id="imagePreview" class="img-border" src="../../Images/blqblq.jpg" alt="Selected Image"/>
```